# PostgreSql - Ordering a mix of numeric strings and number ranges

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**What I have** is a mix of numbers and ranges in a column like so

```
Range
---------
1
3-4
4
5-10
8-9
12-20
2
7
9
11-14
6
10
```

**What I want** is them to be ordered in the following manner

```
Range
---------
1
2
3-4
4
5-10
6
7
8-9
9
10
11-14
12-20
```

**Won't work** - The simple `ORDER BY "Range"` produces the following (as expected)

```
Range
---------
1
10
11-14
12-20
2
3-4
4
5-10
6
7
8-9
9
```

Is there a "simple" way for me to make it order the values (ranges and numbers) as I want them to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use such query:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
ORDER BY 
    CAST(
        CASE WHEN position('-' in Range) > 0 
        THEN substr(range, 0, position('-' in Range)) 
        ELSE Range 
        END 
    as integer)
```

In your `ORDER BY` statement you first extract a number from your range:

- If condition `position('-' in Range) > 0` is met, this means that you have a '-' somewhere in your string, so you should take a number until '-', which is achieved using `substr(range, 0, position('-' in Range))`. E.g. if you have `10-14` in your column, this step only takes `10`.
- If the previous condition is not met then you take the `Range`.

After the above checks are done, you the number. In this case you cast this value to integer, so it correctly orders number (i.e. so 10 comes after 2, etc.)

The above query assumes that you always have the data in the format you specified - either number only or number-number. It would fail for other cases.

Comment: Pointing it out late but what if I have other string values in the column as well such as `Test String` etc, then it won't work, would it?!

Comment: No, it would not work. I updated the answer to specifically tell that

Comment: Alright but how about, if I want it to work for that case as well:)

Comment: It is a much broader question. What should happen with these fields and how they should be ordered?  You need to update the question with these cases or even create a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Given your actual question, this is most easily done using `split_part()`:

```
order by cast(split_part(range, '-', 1) as int)
```

This, of course, assumes that the values in the string are numeric.  If they are not, then ask another question, with example values and how they should be sorted.